# A Certain class of win 7 dialog screens contains blank content

Tags: windows-7

I'm not getting any content in several places including:

- Windows Task Manager (tabs are really tiny.  Nothing in lists)
- Symantec
- Skype (tried reinstalling)
- System Restore

Even Gmail was causing a crash in IE9, and partial rendering in Chrome.

Seems like some subsystem that these programs hook into has corrupted.  Is there a good way to repair this behaviour?

When did this start being a problem?  I powered the laptop off as I was in a rush (not a graceful close).  Restarted, and it said "repair"?  I let it try to repair, and after waiting for a long time, I decided to restart and see if it would started up normally.  Subsequently, I have let it install a windows update.  Had issues with skype before the update, so, I assume that some subsystem is broken.

A "system restore" is not possible right now, as I can't see any content inside the screens that I'd use to start off that action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I limped by for the last four weeks.  Had to go back to the dos prompt for a number of things.

I applied some Windows Updates this morning, rebooted, and now everything works again.  Thanks Microsoft for fixing it up.  I suspect that Microsoft may have caused the issue... but never mind.